Windows "EDIT" control receives ANSI style emoji WM_CHAR (??) on windows 10 from emoji keyboard
I'm trying to implement native win input field for Unity app.
edit control creation:
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall WindowsKeyboard_createTextInput(float x, float y, float width, float height, bool isSingleLine, bool isSecure)
{
    ConvertAndSetCoordinates(x, y, width, height);

    DWORD style = WS_POPUP | (isSingleLine ? ES_AUTOHSCROLL : (ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL));
    DWORD exStyle = WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;

    if (isSecure)
    {
        style |= ES_PASSWORD;
    }
   
    g_hwndTextInput = CreateWindowExW(
        exStyle, L"EDIT", NULL, style,
        g_textInputOffsetX, g_textInputOffsetY, g_textInputWidth, g_textInputHeight,
        g_UnityWindow, NULL, NULL, NULL
    );

    g_isSingleLine = isSingleLine;

    SetWindowSubclass(g_hwndTextInput, EditControlSubclassProc, 0, 0);
    SetFocus(g_hwndTextInput);

    SendMessage(g_hwndTextInput, EM_SETMARGINS, EC_LEFTMARGIN | EC_RIGHTMARGIN, MAKELPARAM(0, 0));
}

When I try to input emoji using windows keyboard (command + .) on win10 it receives two WM_CHAR wParam = 63 messages, on win 11 it receives correct emoji. Pasting strings with emojis or WM_SETTEXT works as expected.
Unity window and Edit control window both are Unicode - IsWindowUnicode() returns true.
"Inspect" tool and "Window Inspector" give same info for win10 and win11.
Empty project with same Edit creation works fine.
Inspectors show same info for Unity/Editor and test project windows.
Where should I look next, or what can cause this bug?
